# How to map custom fields returned to the Auth.Registration handler interface?

Tags: apex, delegated-authentication, user-registration

I am implementing an OpenId Auth. Provider for login to my Salesforce Community. I have the handshake with our IdentityServer working but the /Get UserInfo body contains fields that are not mapped in the UserData class.

For example: 
My claim returns givenname instead of firstName and surname instead of lastName.

The only field that maps correctly is username.

```
    global class CredentialsRegHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{

        global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
            if(data.attributeMap.containsKey('sfdc_networkid')) {
              system.debug('Attribute Map:  ' + data);
                Account a = [SELECT Id FROM account WHERE name='HCSS-AllenM'];
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.accountId = a.Id;
                c.email = data.email;
                c.firstName = data.firstName;
                c.lastName = data.lastName;
                insert(c);
}
}}
```

Here is more info from the debug log:

```
12:24:44.0 (1118472)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|firstName|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1122497)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|firstName|null
12:24:44.0 (1124323)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|lastName|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1126271)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|lastName|null
12:24:44.0 (1128211)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|fullName|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1130057)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|fullName|null
12:24:44.0 (1131577)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|email|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1133763)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|email|null
12:24:44.0 (1135336)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|link|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1137215)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|link|null
12:24:44.0 (1138664)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|username|String|false|false
12:24:44.0 (1140947)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|username|"hdm5"
```

So I think the UserData class is just not mapping them correctly. I know all the data I need is sent back correctly. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you.